# avconv produces still image from still images

Tags: image, video, encode

I am trying to convert a stack of 447 still images (jpg) to video using avconv on ubuntu 14.04

```
avconv -f image2 -i aligned_%04d.tif.jpg -r 10  movie.mkv
```

Output:

```
avconv version 9.16-6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Aug 10 2014 18:16:02 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
Input #0, image2, from 'aligned_%04d.tif.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:17.84, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p, 792x514 [PAR 150:150 DAR 396:257], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn
File 'movie.mkv' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[libx264 @ 0x1811dc0] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x1811dc0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast LZCNT
[libx264 @ 0x1811dc0] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x1811dc0] 264 - core 142 r2389 956c8d8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=3 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=10 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.25 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, matroska, to 'movie.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.20.4
    Stream #0.0: Video: libx264, yuvj420p, 792x514 [PAR 150:150 DAR 396:257], q=-1--1, 1k tbn, 10 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> libx264)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
frame=  179 fps= 53 q=32766.0 Lsize=     158kB time=17.70 bitrate=  73.1kbits/s    s    
video:154kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 2.300587%
[libx264 @ 0x1811dc0] frame I:1     Avg QP:17.62  size: 87993
[libx264 @ 0x1811dc0] frame P:46    Avg QP:16.44  size:  1477
[libx264 @ 0x1811dc0] frame B:132   Avg QP:22.30  size:    26
[libx264 @ 0x1811dc0] consecutive B-frames:  1.7%  0.0%  0.0% 98.3%
[libx264 @ 0x1811dc0] mb I  I16..4:  4.1% 88.4%  7.5%
[libx264 @ 0x1811dc0] mb P  I16..4:  0.1%  0.6%  0.1%  P16..4:  2.8%  0.4%  0.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:95.6%
[libx264 @ 0x1811dc0] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.8%  L0:42.2% L1:57.8% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1811dc0] 8x8 transform intra:82.7% inter:98.4%
[libx264 @ 0x1811dc0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 87.0% 81.3% 53.6% inter: 0.4% 0.8% 0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x1811dc0] i16 v,h,dc,p:  7% 84%  3%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x1811dc0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  9% 29% 18% 17%  4%  3%  4%  5% 12%
[libx264 @ 0x1811dc0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 25% 19%  9% 12%  6%  5%  4%  9% 11%
[libx264 @ 0x1811dc0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 36% 45% 15%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x1811dc0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1811dc0] ref P L0: 96.3%  0.0%  1.9%  1.9%
[libx264 @ 0x1811dc0] ref B L0: 78.5% 12.5%  9.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1811dc0] ref B L1: 95.0%  5.0%
[libx264 @ 0x1811dc0] kb/s:71.22
```

The resulting video runs about 18s, but seems to contain only the first frame. Changing the framerate will still end up with ~18s and only the first frame.

My expectation was: Every image would be used for one frame and the higher the framerate the shorter the video. And of course: The video should contain all images.

Is my expectation wrong? Or what could be the cause for my problem?

My command is mainly based on: https://libav.org/avconv.html#toc-image2-1

Answer (score 0):

I would much rather like to delete the question.

When converting the input frames from tif (which were not accepted by avconv) to jpg, I must have hosed them up. All 447 images were actually a copy of the first one. That explains the video issues, which were no issues really.

Comment: Actually it happened even before, when aligning the images